# Is this correct query in android studio for SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
db.rawQuery("UPDATE " + TABLE_MAIN + " SET " + COL_3_MAIN + " = '" + updatedTime + "' , " + COL_5_MAIN + " = " + COL_5_MAIN + " - 1  WHERE " + COL_1_MAIN + " = "+ ID ,null);
```

I debug my app, but don't know why this query isn't working?

updatedTime is String so I also put the single quotes(') beside it.

It is not giving any error at run time or debug time but updation is not happening!!!

I manually run the query in SQLite database and there is no error. Updation complete.

Comment: use the update function from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475118/only-showing-the-first-saved-icon-on-listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using "rawQuery" to run an update. This is used for SELECTing data and returns a Cursor that you must use to retrieve the results of your query.

To run an UPDATE, you can either use the accepted answer, or use "execSQL" to perform the UPDATE.

The confusion arises, because database developers tend to use the term "query" to apply to any type of database statement whether modifying or retrieving data.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Logic**

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
    data.put("UpdateColumnName", "New_value");
    db.update("TableName", data, "PrimaryColumnName" + " = "+id , null);
```

Comment: but what is problem in my one?

Comment: @AAYUSHCUBING You can try with `ContentValues`. Simple work. No hardcoded query

Comment: what if I have to decrease value of column by one? e.g. col5 = col5-1 . Then what should i write in New_Value field?

Comment: @AAYUSHCUBING For this approach, You need to get values by select statement at first then pass. At first try this simple approach that rows are updating or not.